# Font size larger than set in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

When I set the font size to a specific pixel height, the computed font size is 1.333 times the size I've set in my CSS.  However, if I set the font size as a percentage, the correct size is used.  This happens in *every* browser that I've tried, including Firefox 3.6.28, Firefox 53.0.3 (both 32- and 64-bit), Internet Exploiter, Safari, Chrome and Opera.

Here is a whittled-down example of the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TocMenu Test</title>
    <link href="/style/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {   background:#000000 url('/graphics/l5-back-eso1213a-2K.jpg') repeat fixed;
            color:#ffffe8;
            font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight:normal;
        }
        img
        {   border:0;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #menuRoot *
        {   min-width:0;/* peek-a-boo bug fix for IE7 */
            position:relative;/* peek-a-boo bug fix for IE6 */
        }
        #menuRoot img
        {   padding:3px;
        }
        .tocRoot
        {   padding:0;
        }
        .tocLevel1
        {   font-size:16.8pt;    /* 120% */
            font-weight:bold;
            margin-top:9px;
        }
        .tocLevel2
        {   font-size:15.4pt;    /* 110% */
            font-weight:bold;
            margin-top:6px;
        }
        .tocMenuOpen
        {   background:none;
            color:#ffff66;
            list-style:none;
        }
        .tocMenu1
        {   padding-left:30px;
        }
        .tocLink, a.tocLink
        {   color:#99ff99;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .tocBtn, .tocBtnNot
        {   display:inline-block;
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align:text-top;
            width:14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menuRoot" class="tocMenuOpen tocRoot">
    <li>
        <p class="glueDown">
            <span class="tocBtn" id="menuHome_bn"><img src="/graphics/imgOpen.gif" alt="menu state indicator" /></span>
            <a href="//L5Development.com" class="tocLevel1 tocLink" title="The L5 Development Group - A For-Profit Private Enterprise Space Exploration and Development Program">Home</a>
        </p>
        <ul id="menuHome" class="tocMenuOpen tocMenu1">
            <li>
                <p class="glueDown">
                    <span class="tocBtnNot">&nbsp;</span>
                    <a href="/TodaysNews.php" class="tocLevel2 tocLink" title="News about The L5 Development Group, space travel, space business, and related issues">Today's&nbsp;News</a>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

If I change the `tocLevel1` and `tocLevel2` *`font-size`* values from their pixel heights to the percentage values shown ih the CSS comments, the page works correctly.

Why does *every* browser decide to use a font size one third larger than what is set in the CSS when the `font-size` value is set to a specific height?

Comment: Note: [pt is for print, not the screen.](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `px` (pixels) and `pt` (points) in your font sizes. 120% of 14px would be 16.8**px**, but you've specified the units as points, which are not the same thing, and are larger.

I'd suggest sticking to one unit to make it easier to adjust things relatively. (Or use an absolute measurement as your base size and use relative ones for everything else.)

Comment: Pah!  Yes, you are correct, the problem occurred to me while I was sleeping and confirmed when I got back to my desk...

Comment: Points vs pixels - this is what I get for coding while half asleep